# The lost English dictionary

Tags: american-english, dictionaries

There is an old dictionary of the English language where words are defined from a pessimistic/skeptical/sadistic perspective. I seem to have lost the link to that dictionary in my bookmarks. I wonder if you know what I am talking about and are willing to refresh my memory.

Comment: [_The Devil's Dictionary_](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/972/972-h/972-h.htm), by Ambrose Bierce.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a publication of historical/cultural significance, not directly related to *actual* use of English at all.

Comment: Really now, I think we can live with a question about *The Devil's Dictionary*, can't we?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [*The Devil’s Dictionary*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Devil's_Dictionary) by Ambrose Bierce.

Comment: For those who have not perused this masterpiece, have a look now: http://www.gutenberg.org/files/972/972-h/972-h.htm